# How to read SVG file style properties in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, svg

I need to write fill color of an object in svg file into the variable. I'm using code below to get Node Id's:

```
file_path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets", this.gameObject.name + ".svg");

if (File.Exists(file_path))
{
    file = File.ReadAllText(file_path);
}

scene = SVGParser.ImportSVG(new StringReader(file));

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SceneNode> param in scene.NodeIDs)
{
     names.Add(param.Key);  
}
```

And the problem is that I know how to change fill color but have no idea how to read existing fill color from file. I tried to use `scene.NodeIDs[id].Shapes[0].Fill.Color` but something like this does not exist. That's an example of my SVG file path:

```
<path
   id="path5635"
   d="m 256,342.5 c -2.988,-4.353 -4.224,-16.005 -4.224,-16.005 0,0 -12.516,12.865 -22.585,26.184 -10.07,13.318 -18.961,23.69 -32.018,32.656 -13.06,8.966 -55.413,44.449 -58.141,59.132 0,0 -2.532,8.533 6.468,11.533 9,3 22,-3 31.5,-9.5 9.5,-6.5 31.5,-22 38.374,-33.1 5.995,-9.682 20.626,-38.9 27.126,-49.4 5.843,-9.439 13.5,-21.5 13.5,-21.5 z"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   style="fill:#aa0e0e" />
```

Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can typecast the `Fill` to a [SolidFill](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@1.0/api/Unity.VectorGraphics.SolidFill.html) and assess its `Color` property like this

```
var currentColor = ((SolidFill)scene.NodeIDs[id].Shapes[0].Fill).Color;
```

---

Example:

```
public class SvgExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color color;

    private void Start()
    {
        var file = "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 100 100\">" +
                        "<path id =\"path5635\" " +
                            "d =\"m 256,342.5 c -2.988,-4.353 -4.224,-16.005 -4.224,-16.005 0,0 -12.516,12.865 -22.585,26.184 " +
                            "-10.07,13.318 -18.961,23.69 -32.018,32.656 -13.06,8.966 -55.413,44.449 -58.141,59.132 0,0 -2.532,8.533 " +
                            "6.468,11.533 9,3 22,-3 31.5,-9.5 9.5,-6.5 31.5,-22 38.374,-33.1 5.995,-9.682 20.626,-38.9 27.126,-49.4 " +
                            "5.843,-9.439 13.5,-21.5 13.5,-21.5 z\" " +
                            "style=\"fill:#aa0e0e\" />" +
                   "</svg>";

        var scene = SVGParser.ImportSVG(new StringReader(file));

        color = ((SolidFill)scene.NodeIDs["path5635"].Shapes[0].Fill).Color;
    }
}
```

[image]